# Last step of proposed cubane synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was watching an online lecture on decarboxylation by soda lime and the first few examples were straight forward but after a while a felt that the questions couldn't simply have one effect and maybe other factors should also come into consideration as complexity of structures increases.
[image: REAGENT]

In the above reagent soda lime was added and the teacher said that cubane will be produced however though it might be straight forward based on the mechanism as a carbanion is produced in the intermediate is it correct to directly say that the mechanism should be followed as expected by one pathway without considering any other possibilities such as attempt to relieve angle strain?

Over the course of studying organic chemistry I have realized things often aren't as simple as they appear to be as many factors come into play such as ring closing or bond breaking to relive angle strain.

According to the video the product is Cubane

I know that cubane itself is kinetically stable (primarily due to lack of availability of pathways for decomposition) but the intermediate formed can it not provide any pathways for decomposition?

Comment: What was the yield on the reaction according to the video?

Comment: Sodalime forms the dianion of the carboxylic acid group and SN2 ring closure occurs. Decarboxylation of the anion of cubane carboxylic acid is facile given the kinetic acidity of cubane.  https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00001a051

Comment: @user55119 i didn't get your point about dianion. Isn't a simple anion formed? Also I would appreciate if you elaborated a but more on the kinetic acidity point as it is a relatively new term for me. Maybe formatting as an answer would be a good choice

Comment: Sodalime conditions are quite vigorous. The acidic hydrogen is removed from -CO2H but the alpha hydrogen next to the carboxylate is also deprotonated, thus a dianion. The carbanion displaces chloride. The smaller the C-C-C bond angle the more acidic the C-H bond of the central carbon. The authors claim that cabane is ~63K times more acidic than cyclohexane. Also, cyclopropane is more acidic than methane.